# Interfaces in collections framework

Tags: java, collections

My question is

Interface Set has method `add(E e)` and it extends interface `Collection`. 
Interface `Collection` also has method `add(E e)` 
So why do we need the same method in interface Set , since it already extends interface `Collection`. 
What is the purpose ? 
I am stuck with that

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the two correct answers didn't manage to convince you, I'll try to explain.

Interfaces define contracts - i.e. they define *what* implementors are going (and bound) to do, so that you know that whenever you refer to an object by an interface, it has a strictly defined behaviour, no matter *how exactly* it has been implemented.

Now, this contract comes in two parts:

- method signature - the method signature is the element that is enforced by the compiler - all implementors must conform to the all method signatures defined by the interface
- documented behaviour - when there is more to a method than its method signature, the special behaviour is documented. It again tells the client of the interface what to expect from all implementors, although it does not technigally force implementors to conform to it.

And here comes the concrete `Collection` / `Set` example:

- if you are referring to an object as a `Collection`, then you don't know anything of the behaviour of `add` - whether it allows duplicates or not
- if you are referring to an object as a `Set`, then you are certain that no duplicates are allowed.

This distinction is made by the *javadoc* of the *redefined* `add` method.

Comment: You should probably put “javadoc” in bold just to make it absolutely clear that *this* is where the concrete difference resides. Anyway, very good answer.

Answer (score 12):

[`Set.add`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) refines the contract of [`Collection.add`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29). From the latter's Javadoc:

> Collections that support this operation may place limitations on what elements may be added to this collection. In particular, some collections will refuse to add null elements, and others will impose restrictions on the type of elements that may be added. Collection classes should clearly specify in their documentation any restrictions on what elements may be added.

That's what is done in the Javadoc of `Set.add`, where it states that e.g. duplicate elements are not added to the set.

#### Update: on contracts and interfaces

(including and extending my comments below to round out this answer.)

The *contract* of a method specifies - formally or informally - *what the caller is expected to provide as input for that method, and what is the guaranteed outcome of the method call*. E.g. the contract may state that no `null` parameters are expected, and if the method is passed a `null` parameter, it will throw a `NullPointerException`. The Javadoc of methods in the Collection framework are good examples of such contracts.

Note that some languages allow or even require the *formal definition of contracts*, thus the contracts are compiled into the code and *actively enforced runtime*. [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29) is such a language. However, Java has no such facility; *the contracts defined in Javadoc are not formal*, there is not even a strict format defined for them. These are meant only for human reading, left unnoticed by the JVM. Thus, *breaking a contract in Java may not be immediately noticeable*, only later when the resulting bugs start to appear.

Contracts can be defined both for concrete class methods and abstract/interface methods. The contract of an interface is (should be) binding to all of its implementations. I.e. `HashSet.add`, `TreeSet.add`, `LinkedHashSet.add` etc. all must fulfill the contract of `Set.add` (and may further refine it). An implementation which does not behave according to the contract of `Set.add` breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: Can you please simplify it - What do you mean by contract

Comment: I believe what Peter is trying to say is that `Set.add` describes the method in further detail than what `Collection.add` does. Feel free to take a look at the links I gave below to investigate the differences between the methods. Hope that helps

Comment: @Pratik, the contract of a method specifies - formally or informally - what the caller is expected to provide as input for that method, and what is the guaranteed outcome of the method call. E.g. the contract may state that no null parameters are expected, and if the method is passed a null parameter, it will throw a NullPointerException. The Javadoc of methods in the Collection framework are good examples of such contracts.

Comment: But i think it is an interface does it matter that if it tells that no duplicate elements are allowed or null elements are allowed ....

Comment: It does not implement anything

Comment: @Pratik, yes, but the contract of an interface is (should be) binding to all of its implementations. I.e. `HashSet.add`, `TreeSet.add`, `LinkedHashSet.add` etc. all must fulfill the contract of `Set.add` (and may further refine it). An implementation of `Set.add` which does not behave according to the contract breaks the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: - If you see the implementation of the Set for add method ,it adds specific functionality and finally calls super.add() which is basically AbstractCollection's set method that implements , Collection interface.any datastructure can be added to the Set untill it implements collection interface.

Comment: @Suresh, this is incorrect on several counts: 1) `Set` is an interface, so it has no implementation; 2) concrete implementations in subclasses like `HashSet.add` do _not_ call `super.add()`; 3) it wouldn't even make sense since `AbstractCollection.add` simply throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know extended classes should have the same methods as specified by the superclass. As for the differences between the add methods I suggest you compare the javadocs for the respective `add()`s

- [Set.add(e)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29)
- [Collection.add(e)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add%28E%29)

Comment: well my miss in the terminology, obviously, but I think the point I was trying to make is still valid. :)

Comment: yup ok I got the answer , Thank you for the help