# Method declarations from Collection duplicated in List and Set

Tags: interface, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interfaces in collections framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767794/interfaces-in-collections-framework)

What is the reason that all methods declarations from java.util.Collection interface are duplicated in java.util.List and java.util.Set, both of which extends java.util.Collection

Comment: there was a duplicate of that, let me find it.

Comment: @Bozho Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978570/java-set-interface-and-collection-interface-differences

Comment: it seems it's not only one :)